# Write mysqli query

Tags: mysql

I am learning php and i am confused to write one query, actually I have a database in which i want to fetch quotes from `table_quote` where `qu_status=0` and `ORDER BY id desc`. I want to select 5 quotes from it and want to make `qu_status=1`.

what should I write in query to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to run the query to grab 5 first quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM table_quote WHERE qu_status=0 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

And then using PHP, grab the ids so far fetched, keep them into array varaible, ex, $ids.
So now

`$ids = [id_1, id_2, ..., id_5]`

Now then execute second query:

```
$qry = 'UPDATE table_quote SET qu_status=1 WHERE id in (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```

So I am afraid there wont be simply 1 query, which does select & update together.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query for this...

UPDATE table_quote
SET qu_status=1
WHERE id IN 
(
   SELECT TOP 5 id
   FROM table_quote 
   WHERE qu_status=0
   ORDER BY id desc   -- You need to decide what column you want to sort on
)